# Cast JSON array values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL JSON column containing values such as:

```json
[33173,33386,24272,33499,33526,33347]
```

Would it be possible, with JSON functions, to cast each value in the array to string? The output would be:

```json
["33173","33386","24272","33499","33526","33347"]
```

I'd like to avoid resorting to dirty `REPLACE()` calls.

Comment: What version of MySQL (i.e. what does `SELECT VERSION();` return)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use MySQL 8.0, you can use the [JSON_TABLE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to explode the array into rows, then cast them to CHAR(), then [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) to implode the rows back into a JSON array.

```
set @j = '[33173,33386,24272,33499,33526,33347]';

select json_arrayagg(cast(i as char(5))) as j 
from json_table(@j, '$[*]' columns (i int path '$')) j;
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| j                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ["33173", "33386", "24272", "33499", "33526", "33347"] |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!